# How can I include "live" OSM points of interest on a cartoDB map?

Tags: openstreetmap, carto

I know how to export OpenStreetMap data using http://overpass-turbo.eu/
and build a thematic map in CartoDB.  For example see the toilet map with CartoDB identifier *8385ca6a-49a1-11e4-ad81-0e4fddd5de28*

But how can I get *live* data, or at least something that pulls in new data periodically?

For example if I want to make a map for a hotel, but pull in all area restaurants from OSM?

Comment: So your question is about updating the local OSM data that you render with cartoDB?

Comment: Overpass can return GeoJSON data which in turn can be displayed using Leaflet or OpenLayers. This is pretty much "live" and the Internet has multiple examples how to implement this.

Comment: @scai: Overpass API can only return a JSON format, which is *not* GeoJSON.

Comment: @mmd: Oh sorry, that's correct. But overpass turbo seems capable of returning GeoJSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to add real time data to CartoDB you have two options:

- Using our SQL API in order to make inserts/updates whenever you detect some changes. This requires that you manage the datasource on your end and that you send to CartoDB what you want to edit in your table.
- Using the Sync tables feature: this allows you to use a public resource available online in a URL, Dropbox or Google Drive and keep it synced in a CartoDB table.

Comment: In case of Overpass API, the Sync feature doesn't seem to work at this time, as the OSM XML result is returned with Content-Type "application/osm3s+xml".

Here's an [example link](http://dev.overpass-api.de/api_mmd/interpreter?data=node%0A%20%20%5Bamenity%3Ddrinking_water%5D%0A%20%20%2849.38661921339738%2C8.291587829589844%2C49.59446725601816%2C8.721771240234375%29%3B%0Aout%3B), which fails to sync in CartoDB. Downloading the file in a browser and uploading it again will work without issue.

Comment: I have reported the issue here: https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/issues/5042